# How to index this table (a_level, b_level, item_id)

Tags: mysql, index

I have a table of items, each of it has an a_level, b_level, and an item_id. Any b_level is dedicated to only one a_level (example: b_level 14 is "child" of a_level 2 only)

Lets say we have million of items all of them are INSERTed once and then only SELECTs are requested.

If i SELECT an item based on item_id, then i need to index the item_id column. This will make the MySQL to look all millions of items, which is bad, since i already have the a_level and b_level information. So i guess if i SELECT an item based on a specific level and i have an index on that column, the MySQL will not have to look all millions of items, just the items with that particular level.

If i INDEX both on a_level, b_level (and of course item_id) and SELECT WHERE a_level= b_level= item_id= will it be bad? I guess only INDEX on b_level and item_id and SELECT WHERE b_level= AND item_id= will be enough/the best solution?

So, since i have a_level and b_level (which any b_level as i said is "child" of only one a_level) what will be the most efficient SELECT and INDEXes created for picking up an item?

Comment: Please include `SHOW CREATE TABLE items\G` in your question along with sample queries rather than describing your table and queries in a textual narrative.

Answer (score 1):

Since your table only three columns, this setup can be straightforward.

Here is an ideal table layout for `items`

```
CREATE TABLE items
(
    item_id int not null auto_increment,
    a_level int not null,
    b_level int not null,
    KEY  ai  (a_level,item_id),
    KEY  bi  (b_level,item_id),
    KEY  abi (a_level,b_level,item_id),
    KEY  bai (b_level,a_level,item_id),
    PRIMARY KEY     (item_id)
);
```

Here are the realm of possible queries

- `SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = 100;` (uses the PRIMARY KEY)
- `SELECT * FROM items WHERE a_level = 200;` (uses KEY ai)
- `SELECT * FROM items WHERE b_level = 300;` (uses KEY bi)
- `SELECT * FROM items WHERE a_level = 400 order by b_level` (uses KEY abi ordering all b_level values under a_level 400 and orders item_id under each b_level)

YYou may try out other combinations of `SELECT...GROUP BY...ORDER BY...`. You should also run EXPLAIN on every SELECT query and see which indexes are summoned for query execution. Indexes that do not appear as a chosen index can be eliminated (dropped) over the course of time.

Here were questions you asked?

> If i INDEX both on a_level, b_level (and of course item_id) and SELECT
>   WHERE a_level= b_level= item_id= will it be bad? I guess only INDEX on
>   b_level and item_id and SELECT WHERE b_level= AND item_id= will be
>   enough/the best solution?

Those queries are not bad given the indexes I just presented.

The only reason why the item_id appears in all the indexes is to [make those indexes covering indexes](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/). That way, the retrieval of data is done using the index only, bypassing the table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table structure is the following:

```
items
======================
a_level int not null
b_level int not null
item_id int not null
```

The most efficient index to search by item_id will be on item_id itself. You may want to have other indexes for searches on a_level or b_level when you don't know specific item_id you are looking for.

If you are uisng InnoDB, item_id is int or bigint, and you are not storing multiple rows with same item_id, then you would benefit in having the item_id set up as a primary key. InnoDB creates a clustered index on the primary key. If you don't have a primary key in InnoDB, a hidden row identifier is created for you; it will not be visible, but will take up disk space.