# Sorting on compound Indexes

Tags: index, mongodb, sorting

This may be a novice question but could it be possible query here.

If I have a compound Index as

{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1 }

Is this query possible?

```
db.data.find( { a: {$gte:1,$lt:2}, b: { $gt: 3} },c:"test",d:"yes" ).sort( { b: 1 } )
```

I mean can I use sorting on field b with this compound index and the specified query or do I need to create a separate index on b?

Answer (score 1):

Compound indexes are great for static values

Flip the `WHERE` components so that static values are first

```
db.data.find( { c:"test", d:"yes", a: {$gte:1,$lt:2}, b: {$gt: 3} }).sort( { b: 1 } )
```

Create a different compound index

```
db.data.ensureIndex({c:1},{d:1},{b:1},{a:1})
```

How does it help ?

- Static `c` value
- Static `d` value
- Sorted Range on `b`

One more thing

`{$gte:1,$lt:2}` is really `{$eq:1}`

I have discussed covering indexes and how the order of columns can changes things. In these posts, I talked about it from the MySQL perspective:

- `Apr 11, 2014` : [Why is MySQL not using the index with the higher cardinality?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63047/why-is-mysql-not-using-the-index-with-the-higher-cardinality/63051#63051)
- `Aug 11, 2013` : [How to index for a query with independent range conditions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47917/how-to-index-for-a-query-with-independent-range-conditions/47935#47935)
- `Nov 13, 2012` : [Must an index cover all selected columns for it to be used for ORDER BY?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28592/must-an-index-cover-all-selected-columns-for-it-to-be-used-for-order-by/28640#28640)

Comment: Thanks for input but will sorting work as b is neither first nor last index of teh compound index

Comment: @viren The point here is that the "index selection" and the "order of terms in your query" are very important to MongoDB. The main question you need to ask yourself is "Which terms **reduce** my possible set of results the most?". That is what you want in your "query selection" as the primary concern. The MongoDB query optimiser "can" select an "alternate" index for "sorting purposes", but your prime consideration should always be on "what narrows down the result to the **smallest** set for the **query**", and as a **first** consideration. Sorting is an ancillary exercise.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for your input. Could you please add this as an answer i will update it then.